# Word for compendium of sad (short) stories?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word in the English language that describes a series of unrelated, or only *loosely*-related stories that are all sad or meant to evoke sad, fearful, "negative" emotions?

Sort of like an "anthology/compendium of sad stories"?

Example: "*She had written an X, a collection of unrelated sad stories.*"

Comment: Since tragedies are what you describe as regards their mood, and since we use the suffix "-ette" as diminutive, including in the word "vignettes," which is a word fo loosely-related stories, I would encourage a portmanteau, a word blending the two, and go with "tragedettes."

Comment: just use an adj to define said anthology or compendium or collection